# SSL certificate is listed as supported but it does not allow it

Tags: windows-phone

In my application I need to access a web service using Starfield Class 2 Certification Authority. When running on the emulator everything is working as it should but when debuging on a device I can't access the service. I only get Status code "Not found".

After a while I tried to manually install the certificate on the device and it now works.

On this site they list it as one of the supported certificates.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg521150(v=vs.92).aspx

Does anybody have any knowledge about this? How could this be solved without installing the certificate manually?

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this? I've been trying to troubleshoot a reported issue with my app for ages and have only just been able to track down the cause thanks to a new phone!

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone doesn't seem to support cope well with some UCC certificates.

The fix for me was replacing the UCC with a wildcard certificate.